# TryParse/ParseExact on string fails to convert to format ("dddd dd MMMM") if adding months after the new year

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, formatexception

My goal is to convert a string parameter with format '*dddd dd MMMM*' into a DateTime object. The string parameter itself is formed from fetching a relative date from today, some months in the future, for example `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(5).ToString("dddd dd MMMM");`. When using the TryParse/ParseExact method to convert the parameter string back to a DateTime that is after the new year (in this case after January 1st 2019) I get the following error:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
>   because the day of week was incorrect.*

When I attempt to pass a parameter of the required format before the new year, it is accepted as valid. Could it be something to do with a Leap Year calculation that is needed or is there another reason for this?

Thanks,

Comment: *My goal is to convert a string parameter with format 'dddd dd MMMM'* it doesn't make sens ... there is no year part in this format

Comment: Can you please show [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem? Your format has only day and month parts but you are mentioning year part as well.

Comment: What exact value are you passing for the string?  Are you sure the day of the week is valid for the date?  (This is the implied error from the error message...)  Note that 5 months from Now is 2020....

Comment: Obviously this needs an explicit year to actually be valid. Compare `.AddMonths(5)`, `.AddMonths(17)` -- same date, but with a different weekday. Nothing to do with leap years, it'll fail whenever your date crosses the year boundary. This format is simply not suitable for roundtripping.

Comment: Skip the day of the week :            string dateStr = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(5).ToString("dddd dd MMMM");
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr.Substring(dateStr.IndexOf(" ")).Trim(), "dd MMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @jdweng: sure, that will not give an error (if you do the `ToString` with the invariant culture as well). But it will also not produce the original date, of course, since the original had 2020 and the reconstituted date will necessarily use 2019.

Comment: A date is made up of month, day and year. If you're not including a year, it's not a date, and you can't expect date functions to work properly with it. There's no way of knowing that it's *some months in the future* without a year being provided, because there's no known base to start with in order to determine that it's *next year* you want.

Comment: "The string parameter itself is formed from fetching a relative date from today, some months in the future" -- so you *do* have the exact value at some point. Why do you need the roundtrip to string and back again? Why not keep the exact value? And if you do need to serialize it (not necessarily *display* it!) why not use a format where you lose the least amount of information?

Comment: My code will default to the current year.  What year does your code use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the year being a leap-year... the reason it's succeeding for dates from this year but failing for dates from next year is that your format doesn't include the year, so .Net is making an assumption that the year is *this* year, and a day, month-day and month from next year will not parse.

For example:

`"Saturday 16 March"` -> parses without error, since this is valid now, in 2019.

`"Monday 16 March"` -> error as described.  This is a valid combination of day, month-day and month in 2020, but it's not valid for this year, 2019.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. I shall update the format to include the year

Comment: @Stix: as long as updating the format is an option, strongly consider using ISO 8601, as it's a standard specifically designed to be free of such ambiguities. You can use the `s` format specifier to get it (or the `o` format specifier to get it including a time zone offset), or `yyyy-MM-dd` if you don't need the time. Formats that include names of anything should only be used for displaying to the end users, not for values that are supposed to be parsed back by machines.

Comment: You're welcome @Stix.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Remember to pass on thanks by upvoting and accepting! ;)

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you, I will look into ISO 8601 as a possibility

Answer (score 0):

[Ian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58413482#58413482) is correct, since the day of the week doesn't match.  That is the correct answer.

However - For posterity I'll also point out that there is still a leap year bug in such code.  Consider the following:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2020, 2, 29); // a leap day
string format = "MM/dd"; //any format with month and day but without year
string s = dt.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This code seems like it should always work, since the format is the same both when creating the string and when parsing it.  However, since the year is not part of the format, it will only work when run in a leap year.  When executed during a common year, a `FormatException` will be thrown with the message:

> The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

This is because the `DateTime` object *must* have  a year, so if one was not provided then it uses the *current* year.  When I run this today, in 2019, it tries to create the date `2019-02-29`, which doesn't exist.

Incidentally, the same thing can happen when parsing XML.  The XSD data type [`gMonthDay`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#gMonthDay) provides a month and a day without a year, by placing an extra hyphen in the year position, such as `"--12-31"` which can be converted using `XmlConvert.ToDateTime`.  It normally works with all days of the year, but `XmlConvert.ToDateTime("--02-29")` only works if the current year is a leap year - even though it is explicitly allowed by the XSD spec.